# Why is matrix times its transpose, covariance matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, covariance

I understand that matrix is a linear transformation of a vector space and matrix multiplication is applying one transformation over another. I couldn't get a geometric intuition as to why multiplying matrix by its transpose give covariance matrix.

Comment: Is [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325713/why-multiply-a-matrix-with-its-transpose) helpful to you?

Comment: I am still not convinced why it has anything to do with variance?

Comment: Ok. Did you saw [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37398/what-is-the-geometric-interpretation-of-the-transpose?rq=1) as well?

Comment: Yes. It is not what I am looking for. I want to understand why variance comes into the picture.

Comment: Any visual/geometric interpretation is helpful

Comment: [Every symmetric positive semi definite matrix is a covariance matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489632/is-every-symmetric-positive-semi-definite-matrix-a-covariance-of-some-multivaria) and every matrix of the form $A^\top A$ is obviously symmetric and PSD.

Comment: @Jay Also it's not clear what you mean by a "geometric intuition" as to something yielding a covariance matrix. Having a geometric explanation would require a geometric representation of a covariance matrix or perhaps the concept of covariance, but it's not clear what that would be

Comment: @Jay A correction to my earlier comment: can you understand that if the rows of an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ have mean zero, then $\frac 1{m-1} AA^T$ gives the usual estimate for covariances based on each row of samples?